# Cannot migrate deprecated unlocked package2 component since Winter 20'

Tags: salesforcedx, error, package, unlocked-package

I am unable to migrate a package2 member from one unlocked package to another.

Before Winter 20', as per [these instructions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_migrate_metadata.htm), deprecating a member from the first package and installing the second package with the same member would make it migrate successfully.

However since Winter 20 release, I get the error:

> Cannot add component of type:CustomField named:null subjectId:00N5E000003OEy2UAG to another package because it is a managed installed component., Details: package.xml: Cannot add component of type:CustomField named:null subjectId:00N5E000003OEy2UAG to another package because it is a managed installed component.

My packages are for sure not managed (unlocked). I find weird that querying [Package2Member](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_package2member.htm) gives me `SubjectManageableState: deprecated` instead of `deprecatedEditable`.

The only way for us to migrate the metadata for now is to remove the component from the installed packages page which is not at all CI/CD compliant.

Is there something I am missing from the last release ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This incompatibility has been fixed by Salesforce with hotfix release.